# Интерфейс для функции, которая получает массив ключей для отбрасывания

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

Есть функция, которая получает пропсы и массив ключей. В результате она должно согласно массиву исключить эти значения и вернуть результат.

```ts
interface IProps {
  disabled: string[];
  props: {
    [key: string]: any
  }
}

function func({
  disabled = [],
  props = {}
}: IProps):TFilteredProps => {...}
```

Каким образом можно описать интерфейс который включает в себя все поля пришедшие от IProps за исключением тех полей, что приходят в массиве `disabled`

Comment: у вас `TFilteredProps` будет в каждом конкретном случае иметь разные поля, такое нельзя сделать на `ts`, да и вообще кажется, это уже какой-то супердинамический тип

Comment: @ThisMan, а есть вообще какие-то способы динамически создавать типы?

Comment: Utility Types вам в помощь, изучайте: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html

Comment: @RTW проблема тут в том, что я как я понял, ТС хочет иметь на выходе тип, который зависит от параметров, которые он передал в функцию. Это не возможно в рамках ts, так как ts работает на этапе сборки, на этапе выполнения никаких типов уже нет

Comment: @ThisMan ну ему то не рантайм нужны типы, просто чтобы у переменой которой присваивается результат выполнения функции был тип без некоторых свойств, а это можно сделать.

Comment: @RTW _без некоторых св-в_ которые передаются в рантайме же...

Comment: @ThisMan не вижу подобного в вопросе. const x = (y:Y): Omit<Y, 'prop'> => 1

Comment: > _IProps за исключением тех полей, что приходят в массиве disabled_
как вы узнаете какие поля пришли в `disabled`, мне, кажется, речь именно про это

Comment: @ThisMan ну он же передаёт их в эту же функцию...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### возможно ли?

да, возможно, но есть ограничения

### какие ограничения ?

```
const obj = { a: '', b: '', c: '', }
const arr = ['a', 'c']
// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"a" | "c" | "b"'.ts(2345)
```

TS должен знать, что вы создаёте на массив строк, а массив ключей объекта.

### но это решаемо, в той или иной степени.

[там песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?alwaysStrict=false&allowUnusedLabels=true&target=99#code/CoRgXABA3gUAkAYwPYDsDOAXCAzJSIC8EAPMADQQCKEApgB4Y0oAmaEA1jQJ5LYTAA+ABQAHAE5IRaSOQgA6BQEdIlANoBdAJSQA8gFsAlhlIVKAwuZQBXADY2IAQzYOUXANzwA9J4gBaMr7wyOhYSABGAFaEOHhCUI6QAOSJFGFJKRAI6RQAvhSJDhmJCImaXj7+gXDhEXIObhDetGJi8DVyYR7VkXIIDU00LTA5ME2VMMAATJCwiKiYMfhEJlS0DEysHNy8-MLiktL8FApyylQa2hD6RitmFhDWdo7Orl1jAUHzWA4t0aoFRRK6k+IQgNWiuCQQngcHiDmyEDSEGSFCyyIyeRhJx+YkaPgAgmIAOZWPRMUJ8DBcEQ0ZGYMQGFBExIQAxsFBIb5oNAGIkoBxhGy0jD4EQ-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)

```
T1: {
    const foo = <T, Q extends keyof T>(props: T, ...q: Q[]): Omit<T, Q> => null as any;
    // -,-
    const obj = foo({ a: '', b: '', c: '', }, 'a', 'c')
    // -,-
    obj.a; // err
    obj.b;
    obj.c; // err
}
```

```
T2: {
    const foo = <T, Q extends keyof T>(props: T, ...q: Q[]): Omit<T, Q> => null as any;
    // -,-
    const arr = ['a', 'c']
    const obj = foo(
        { a: '', b: '', c: '', },
        ...arr // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"a" | "c" | "b"'.ts(2345)
    )
    // -,-
    obj.a; // нет ошибки - плохо
    obj.b;
    obj.c; // нет ошибки - плохо
}
// -,-
T3: {
    const foo = <T, Q extends keyof T>(props: T, ...q: Q[]): Omit<T, Q> => null as any;
    // -,-
    const qq = <T, Q extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...q: Q[]) => q;
    // -,-
    const obj_base = { a: '', b: '', c: '', }
    // -,-
    const arr = qq(obj_base, 'b', 'c')
    const obj = foo(obj_base, ...arr)
    // -,-
    obj.a;
    obj.b; // err
    obj.c; // err
}
```

```
T4: {
    type $q<T, K> = { [K in keyof T]: any }
    const foo = <T, Q extends Partial<{ [K in keyof T]: any }>, K extends keyof Q,>(props: T, o: Q): Omit<T, K> => null as any;

    const obj = foo({
        a: '',
        b: '',
        c: '',
    }, { c: '' })

    obj.a;
    obj.b;
    obj.c; // err
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще подсказали такой вариант, сразу же с учетом, что могут пустой объект в функцию передать.

```ts
interface IProps<P extends object, D extends keyof P> {
    disabled?: D[];
    props?: P;
}
function func<P extends object, D extends keyof P>({
  disabled,
  props,
}: IProps<P, D>): Omit<P, D> | {} { return ... }
```